# Extracting specific elements from list python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, extract

I am working on this bot that extracts the urls from a specific page. I have extracted all the links and put them in a list now I can't seem to get realist urls(lead to other sites starting with http or https) out from the list and append them to another list or delete the ones that don't start with http. Thanks in advance

```
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    #get all the links from bing about cancer
    site = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=cancer&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=cancer&sc=8-4&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=E56491F36028416EB41694212B7C33F2"
    urls =[]
    true_links = []
    r = requests.get(site)
    html_content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        link = link.get("href")
        urls.append(str(link))
        #urls.append(link.get("href"))

    #print map(str, urls)
    #REMOVE GARBAGE LINKS

    print len(urls)
    print urls

main()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem?  If I run your code as it is written, `urls` is populated with a list of URLs, many of which point to sites other than bing (e.g., `...'http://www.coursera.org/course/clinicaltrials', 'http://www.coursera.org/course/clinicaltrials', 'http://www.khanacademy.org/science/health-and-medicine/respiratory-system-diseases/lung-cancer/v/lung-cancer-complications',...`)  Can you explain how the results you are getting differ from the results you want?

Comment: I want the links to that lead to an actual site rather than a script or a stylesheet (For example i want http://www.webmd.com/cancer/default.htm not  /script.js or /styles.css

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlparse.urljoin`:

```
link = urlparse.urljoin(site, link.get("href"))
```

This will create absolute URLs out of relative ones.

You should also be using `html_content = r.text` instead of `html_content = r.content`. `r.text` takes care of using the proper encoding.